# Umlaute in tags are only replaced with one instance?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-autocomplete

While messing around with the tag system, I noticed that multiple Umlaute (`öäü`) are replaced with only a single instance of their counterpart.

Example:

```
[vööörg] becomes [vorg]
[füür] becomes [fur]
```

Reproduce:

- Got the favorite tags field
- Enter "vööörg"
- Hit "Add"
- The tag "vorg" has been added to your list

Additionally, there's no validation of an entered tag in the "Tags" line of a question if you click onto another tag.

Reproduce:

- Start or edit a question
- Add at least one valid tag in the tags list
- Enter `[vööörg]`
- Do not press space after the "g" but instead click on the valid tag left of it
- The tag `[vööörg]` is now in the list
- Hitting "Submit" now will break the tags into: `[support]` `[v]` and `[rg]`

Is that by design?

Comment: Sounds like someone used regex, two problems, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those are actually two totally independent bugs. But they're both fixed in the next build. Thanks!